# What options do I have for long running processes in my C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm working on a console app that kicks off a fairly long running process (2-3 minutes).  What options are available for displaying progress, or even just writing a "." to screen every few seconds so the user knows the app hasn't stopped responding?

Comment: you can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Is the long running process your code? If so why not just do a write command in the loop or whatever the slow part is?

Comment: @John: The process occurs inside one of our class libraries, and is initiated with a single method call. There's not really a good place for me to inject a console.writeline(".")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) 3 ways to do this:

- Simplest: On program start, set a global variable to false, then start a thread that writes a dot to the console, Thread.Sleep()s a second, repeats until the variable is set to true. On your main thread do your work, when finished set the variable to true and then Join() the other thread.
- Still simple: Add another global variable to the mix, type int. In your worker thread increase it, whenever some progress is made, on the console writer thread reduce interval to say 250ms, but draw a dot only if progress counter has changed. This gives an idea of how fast your app progresses
- A bit advanced: Create a boolean as in first step plus an `AutoResetEvent`, let the console writer thread repeatedly wait on the event, when app makes progress Set() the event. When finished set boolean to true and Set() again before Join()ing. The advanced part in this is to know, in what portions to report progress.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is if your application has an incremental loop then you could put a simple full stop on the the console. Not nice, but it does give an indication of "I'm alive".

But that approach can result in too much info (too many characters going to console) or too few as your hooking into a bit of the code that does not really have that responsibility.

So, perhaps a nicer way that you can reuse is to create a console user class that is run in a thread with a 1 second tick. It can use backspacing and the good old | / | / - sequence to give the impression of something rotating. It can also check for key presses to allow the user to exit.

Another option, depending on the nature of your users, is to use a logging framework like **NLog**. That way your implementation is UI independent and you can see what is happening in more or less detail at run time in the console, from another machine, whatever.